# Only one jQuery event runs per refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

Only one jQuery event runs per refresh of the page.  What am I doing that's so wrong?

```
$("#contact_link_email").on("click",function(){
  $("#contact-form").replaceWith('<h2>Email heading</h2>');
});

$("#contact_link_facebook").on("click",function(){
  $("#contact-form").replaceWith('<h2>Facebook heading</h2>');
});

$("#contact_link_twitter").click(function(){
  $("#contact-form").replaceWith('<h2>Twitter heading</h2>');
});

$("#contact_link_gplus").click(function(){
  $("#contact-form").replaceWith('<h2>GPlus heading</h2>');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Once one of those events runs, `$("#contact-form")` doesn't reference anything. If you want to replace it with something, try making that something have the same `id`.

Comment: Hi Thanks. Here is the form... that the id references<form id="contact-form" action="" method="post">
 <div   class="control-group">
   <label  class="control-label"  for="name"></label>
   <div   class="controls">
    <i class="icon-user"></i> <input  class="span3" type="text"  name="name"  id="name"  placeholder="Name">
   </div>
  </div></form>

Comment: So rather than replacing the form, have a heading right above it that you replace/modify in the method, in addition to changing the function of the form as specified.

Comment: Thanks Jake,  I realise what I've done wrong.  When I click the first link, it replaces the contact form correctly.  When I click the second link, there is no form there to replace.  I need to be able to replace the current link showing.  Do you have any ideas?  Thanks again for your help.